# Use Bootstrap with Abstract email form Wagtail

Tags: wagtail

I want to bootstrap with my form wagtail.

```
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.admin.panels import FieldPanel, InlinePanel, MultiFieldPanel, FieldRowPanel
from wagtail.contrib.forms.models import AbstractFormField, AbstractEmailForm
from wagtail.fields import RichTextField

from wagtailcaptcha.models import WagtailCaptchaEmailForm


class FormField(AbstractFormField):
page = ParentalKey("ContactPage", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="form_fields")


class ContactPage(WagtailCaptchaEmailForm):
    # Hérite de AbstractEmailForm
    template = "contact/contact_page.html"
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)

content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('intro'),
    InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Champs du formulaire"),
    FieldPanel('thank_you_text'),
    MultiFieldPanel([
        FieldRowPanel([
            FieldPanel('from_address', classname="col-6"),
            FieldPanel('to_address', classname="col-6"),
        ]),
        FieldPanel('subject')
    ], heading="Configurations des adresses"),
]
```

In my html :

```
 <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}

            <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
        </form>
```

How to use bootstrap with this wagtail form please ?

I wanted to try the classnames directly in my model but it doesn't seem to work. Is there another method?

thks

Answer (score 0):

I use the following template rather than the built-in render method. I didn't like the formatting for checkboxes and the reCaptcha:

```
    <form action="{% pageurl page %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %} 
      
      {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %} 
        {{ hidden_field }} 
      {% endfor %} 
      {% if form.errors or form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          {{ self.form_error_warning }}
        </div>            
      {% endif %}
      {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          {% for error in form.non_field_errors %} {{ error }} {% endfor %}
        </div>
      {% endif %}

      <div class="form-group">
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %} 
          {% field_class field as field_class %}
          {# Check box not displaying correctly by default, use case here #}
          {% if field_class == "checkbox" %}
            <div class="form-check mt-4 ml-1">
              {% if form.is_bound %} 
                {% if field.errors %} 
                  {% render_field field class="form-check-input is-invalid form-check-input-sm" %} 
                {% else %} 
                  {% render_field field class="form-check-input is-valid form-check-input-sm" %} 
                {% endif %} 
              {% else %} 
                {% render_field field class="form-check-input form-check-input-sm" %} 
              {% endif %} 
              <div class="font-label pt-0 pb-1">
                {{ field.label_tag }}
              </div>
            </div>
          {% else %}
            <div class="font-label pt-2 pb-1">
              {% if field.name != "wagtailcaptcha" %}{{ field.label_tag }}{% endif %}
            </div>
            {% if form.is_bound %} 
              {% if field.errors %} 
                {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid form-control-sm" %} 
              {% else %} 
                {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid form-control-sm" %} 
              {% endif %} 
            {% else %} 
              {% if field.name == "wagtailcaptcha" %}
                {% render_field field %} 
              {% else %}
                {% render_field field class="form-control form-control-sm" %} 
              {% endif %}
            {% endif %} 
          {% endif %}
          {% if field.errors or field.help_text %}
            <div class="row">
              {% if field.name == "wagtailcaptcha" %}
                {% if field.errors %}
                  <ul class="list-unstyled pl-3">
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                      <small class="text-danger">
                        <li>{{ error }}</li>
                      </small>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </ul>
                {% endif %}
              {% else %}
                <div {% if field.errors %}class="col"{% else %}class="col-auto"{% endif %}>
                  {% if field.help_text %}
                    <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text|linebreaksbr }}<br>&nbsp;</small>
                  {% else %}
                    <small>&nbsp;</small>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div {% if field.errors %}class="col-auto text-right"{% else %}class="col"{% endif %}>
                  {% if field.errors %}
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                      {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <small class="text-danger">
                          <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        </small>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          {% endif %} 
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">{{ page.submit_button_text }}</button>
    </form>
```

That renders out something like:[image]